# How can I get attributes from one factory inside of another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Here is what I am using in my specs:

```
let(:family) { create :family } 
let(:picnic) { build :picnic, cook: family.dad, assistant: family.son }
```

It works, however, I would prefer to move this logic into picnic_factory.rb and just use let(:picnic) { build :picnic } in my specs.

There is a scope in Picnic that checks if family.dad and family.son are unique to the same Family. I need to create a family factory and then I need to use that to create a picnic factory.

pseudocode:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  FactoryGirl.create(:family) -> points towards family_factory.rb
  factory :picnic do 
    cook { family.dad }
    assistant { family.son }    
  end   
end
```

Comment: that functionality is available out of the box. btw factorygirl is deprecated. use FactoryBot

Comment: @BKSpurgeon what is the correct syntax? i cant get it to work.

Comment: did the below syntax work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- assume you have ***already defined*** a picnic factory and also a family factory.

**(Warning: Untested code):**

perhaps define something like this:

```
factory :family_picnic, parent: :picnic do
    family = create(:family)
    cook { family.dad }
    assistant { family.son }  
end
```

Use it like this:

```
    FactoryBot.create(:family_picnic)
```